# Python to HTMl Output - Return HTML while running SubProcess in background

Tags: python, html, subprocess, return, python-multiprocessing

I am using python to output html. So far is working well however I'm now at a point where I need to run a long python function. Given the method to output the html uses a python return statement. When I run the long script the HTML does not output until the long script has completed compiling. What would be the best method to output some HTML - e.g. "Loading - Please Wait.." whilst the long process is compiling? I've attempted something similar to the snippet below using two python scripts and the subprocess module.

main.py

```
import subprocess
import waitScript

def loadingPage():
   loadingOutput = """
      <div class="container-fluid">
         <h1> Please wait - Loading files..</h1>
         <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
            <span class="sr-only"></span>
         </div>
      </div>
   """
   subprocess.call(['python', 'waitScript.py'])

   return(loadingOutput)
```

And here is the python script which is called - which simply waits 15 seconds.

waitScript.py

```
import time
time.sleep(15)
```

My mis-understanding of the subprocess module was that it was able to run the waitScript in the background while main.py was still able to return the html. But each time it seems to wait 15 seconds and then return the html.

Is there any way I can output or return the html before the time consuming script is still running? I'm beginning to think there is a better module for what I'm trying to achieve but so far have had no luck finding one.